# Law of the unconscious statistician with stochastic processes

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes

I would like to know if  the law of the unconscious statistician can be applied for stochastic processes.

If so, can someone provide a reference?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The law of the unconscious statistician is a basic theorem of probability, and it can be applied whenever you know the distribution of a random variable and want the expected value of a function of it.  That does happen a lot in stochastic processes.  Just about any text on stochastic processes should include tons of examples.

Comment: Thank you. I went over some textbooks however when coming to the stochastic process they did not mention nothing about LOTUS rule.

Comment: In many cases this is used routinely without comment.  That's why it's called "unconscious".